# Mobile app authentication for existing API

Tags: spring, mobile, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have application with Spring security. It's REST api for Angular SPA. It uses session and cookie mechanism. Now I want to access this api from mobile application (Nativescript). I spent some time searching for best way to authenticate mobile app user. In the most cases oauth2 and jwt tokens are advised. So I've done reasearch on this and decided to add additional (seperate) authentication only for mobile application. So Angular app still will be using session with path api/... and mobile app will be using token mechanism with path /api/mobile/... (underneath it will be the same api but with different prefix).

I've decided to use OAuth2 and its Spring integration. I've read documentation and I'm consfused. Why they always mention about authentication provider (Google, Github, Facebook)? I don't want to force my users to login via other service. I want to allow them login with credentials they already registered with in my application. How this social login even related with oAuth authorization server? All examples they've provided use some other services.

I've also tried to add my authorization server in my existing app. I've successfully retrieved token. But now I don't understand all this relationships. There is authorization server that keeps client id and client server. But why /auth/token endpoint needs another authentication? So mobile app needs to provide 3 different credentials - user credentials, client id and secret and token endpoint credentials.

Did I miss something? I know that OAuth is only specification and Spring is implementation of it. But I'm under impression that Spring overcomplicates this. And do I need oauth at all since I have only 1 type of resource?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {
        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(clientId)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(clientSecret))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("refresh_token", "authorization_code", "password", "implicit")
                .scopes(scopeRead, scopeWrite)
                .resourceIds(resourceIds);
    }
}
```

Comment: The authorization server is part of the OAuth2 specification. In the specification it is stated "Access tokens are issued to third-party clients by an authorization server with the approval of the resource owner.". If you do not want to use access tokens and an authorization server, then you likely do not need OAuth2 in your application.

Comment: I can use tokens and authorization server. I'm not sure if I understand relationship authorization server with authentication providers (Github, Facebook etc.). As far as I understood these providers are optional and I can use my authentication mechanism. On the other hand in all examples on Spring repo they use Google or Facebook.
So I'm looking for working example of token authentication that uses credentials from DB instead of third parties. Or other way to authenticate user from mobile application.